# How to convert Coredump .gz file so that I can read it

Tags: linux, core-dump

I have coredump file in `.gz` format (which I am not aware of) and I want to convert it, so that I can read it.

Is there a way I can use `coredumpctl` to read the `.gz` core dump file?

Comment: It is already in bytes, there is nothing to do. Why do you think that you can not send it?

Comment: Its in .gz format which I am not aware of. Is there a way instead of accessing the directory where the coredump file is, I ask `coredumpctl` to get the coredump file for me. Then I don't have to be root to access the coredump file.

Comment: First stop it with the being root. Why is it that when ever a user does not know what they are doing, they do it as root. This is a sure way to break things. You do not have to be root to convert a file.

Comment: I have added an answer, but there are a lot of confusing ideas in this question. I suspect that you are using words, that you have heard (cargo cult). Please just use ordinary words. There is, usually, no need for technical specialist words.

Comment: the aim is to call coredumpctl and get the coredump file. Is it possible to do it without root access?

Comment: This seems like a new question: it would depend on where the core dumps are stored. Feel free to ask another question, keep the language simple, avoid jargon (jargon if not used exactly right will be confusing, so is best avoided.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

files ending in .gz are usually gnu-zip files. Check by typing `file «filename»`, if should report gnu zip.

If so it is a compressed file, you can un-compress it by typing `gunzip «filename»`.